# Move all files not starting from a specific letter

Tags: linux

I am trying to move files from a folder to another location. I want to move all files except those which start with 'c'.

This is what I am trying

```
mv a* b* d*...............z*
```

Obviously this is a wrong way. Can anyone tell me the right way? I am using linux ( RHEL 6 )

Comment: A simpler approach which requires no additional knowledge beyond what you already know would be `mkdir /tmp/c; mv c* /tmp/c; mv * /another/location; mv /tmp/c/* .` That is, invert your problem. Hide everything that starts with "c", deal with the remaining files, and then unhide the "c" files.

Comment: This is very unorthodox, but effective. Nice !!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `[^c]` means "everything that is not *c*", you can use the following expression:

```
mv [^c]* another_dir
```

---

> What if I have to left two letters? `mv [^c]* [^d]* another_dir`?

In that case use the following:

```
mv [^cd]* another_dir
```

#### Tests

See the output of `ls` when using these regexs:

```
$ ls
a23  abc  b23  bd23  c23  cd23  d23
$ ls [^c]*
a23  abc  b23  bd23  d23
$ ls [^cd]*
a23  abc  b23  bd23
```

Comment: excellent. What if I have to left two letters? mv [^c]* [^d]* another_dir ?

Comment: In that case, `mv [^cd]* another_dir` would make it, as [^xyz] syntax means: except matching x, y or z.

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
mv [a-b,d-z]* destination
```

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me with my problem - moving all items starting with a letter but not with a number.